# PostgreSQL check on columns of related tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have this table structure (it's Python/SQLAlchemy-like, but I believe it's almost pseudocode):

```py
class Sport:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Team:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sport_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sports.id')) # relationship to Sport

class League:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sport_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sports.id')) # relationship to Sport

class Match:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    team_home_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id')) # relationship to Team
    team_away_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id')) # relationship to Team
    league_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("leagues.id")) # relationship to League
```

I'd like to introduce some constraint on matches (or a trigger etc.) to ensure that related `Team`s and `League` all have the same related `Sport`.

What SQL do I have to issue on my DB to create such check or, ideally, is there a way to achieve this with SQLAlchemy (all the classes are derived from DeclarativeBase, I just omitted it in the code)?

Answer (score 0):

Two easy options

- Have `Team` point to `League`, not `Sport`. This might be problematic if same team can play in several leagues (Real Madrid plays football both in *La Liga* and *UEFA Champions League*)
- Have `Match` hold `Sport id`, make it a part of all the three foreign keys. Unless your `League` has other fields, it becomes unnecessary.

Other options might include something like:

- Create `Participation` which tells which team participates which League (possibly in which season). Aston Villa played 2019 Championship but 2020 Premier League. Link `Participation` to a `Match`es instead of `Team`s.
- Have only `League` point to `Sport`. Sparta Praha plays both ice hockey and football. (Had to pick this example, since you seem to be from .cz :P)

Comment: as for Teams not pointing to sport - I want to have separate teams for different sports, as they don't have anything common except for the name

Comment: Excluding a change in the table layout won't get you far. Use views on the actual tables as an API for the application so that you don't have to rewrite the code whenever you change the tables.

Comment: b) If Match has Sport_id as part of it's all three foreign keys, that solves the problem in your original question: "I'd like to introduce some constraint on matches (or a trigger etc.) to ensure that related Teams and League all have the same related Sport". One more option: Make inserting matches and changing foreign keys a stored procedure that takes care of your RI. To really enforce it, see CREATE FUNCTION...SECURITY DEFINER